# Setup Node-JS to run as a website without a port on a windows machine with apache

Tags: node.js, windows, apache

This has been a very difficult thing to investigate as well as configure, everyone oneline just have half documentation, for some reasons everyone is concentrated on the running of nodejs on the commandline, or if not, they want to run it on http://localhost:8080.

What I need is a full documentation from installation, configuration, vhost setup, to running a nodejs website such as http://node.local/ website on my work machine.

Please assist, I have been googling for 3 days on this, have not found anything, I need to setup http://node.local website fully running nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy http server. For example [nginx](https://nginx.org) is pretty easy to configure.
And it will proxy requests from port 80 to port 3000, for example.
[Here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) you can find quick guide to setup one.